# Unit testing a web service client from NetBeans

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jax-ws

I have a project that contains both the ws client and service (JAX-WS). Is there a way of having the ws deploy during automated testing such that I can have my client tests encompass the calls to the service?

Obviously this would require deployment to an application server... or is this kind of testing ill-advised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a suitable solution to this problem. Using embedded Tomcat (7.0.11), I was able to successfully deploy my web-service programmatically during the running of the unit test.

```
tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
tomcat.setPort(8084);
tomcat.addWebapp("/", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/build/web");
tomcat.setHostname("localhost");
tomcat.enableNaming();
tomcat.start();
```

This approach suited me well as I wanted to automate the testing of a web-service client. As *Piyush* pointed out, soapUI is a perfect way to perform integration testing.

**Edit**

If you are using `context.xml` you will need to define it like so:

```
Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/build/web");
File contextFile = new File("META-INF/context.xml");
ctx.setConfigFile(contextFile);
```

Comment: Would it be the same sort of thing with Glassfish?

Answer (score 1):

- This is a good [article](http://www.tmro.net/2009/03/unit-test-jax-rs-using-java-6-and-junit-4/) on unit testing RESTful service. You can also use [REST-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) to test REST services and validating the response using Junit in Java.
- For functional testing, you can use [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/).
- For JAX-WS services, check this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-soa-autotest2/). You can also check on the Spring way of testing JAX-WS [here](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/03/writing-and-testing-jax-ws-clients.html). You can as well do unit testing from Netbeans by following documentation mentioned [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/rfish/msis531/code/jaxws20.html#registry)

How are you generating your service? 
What kind of Web Services are they? Isn't your generated service a regular POJO?